# Google Places API - Get more than 10 photos from Details Response?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Is there any way to get more than 10 photos back in the photos array? I'm using the JavaScript API v3. Perhaps a separate service to get more photos?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_responses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. As per the documentation, the API returns a maximum of 10 photos. [Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_photos)

Comment: A link to where you found this information would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, noticed that. Is there perhaps a different service I could use the place id with to get more photos?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: *photos[] — an array of photo objects, each containing a reference to an image. A Place Search will return at most one photo object. Performing a Place Details request on the place may return **up to ten photos***
link https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search