# Retrieving more than 10 photos from Google Places API

Tags: python, google-maps, google-api, google-places-api, google-python-api

I am using the Google Places API to retrieve places and their correspondent photos. The problem I've found is that Google does not allow you to download more than 10 photos from a DETAILS RESPONSE, as exposed here:

[Google Places API - Get more than 10 photos from Details Response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29856695/google-places-api-get-more-than-10-photos-from-details-response)

Since I really need getting more than 10 photos, my question is if there is any way of doing this, beyond the Google Maps API. If not, do you think will they implement this any soon?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The feature request exists: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830750. Feel free to star it to add your vote.

Comment: Any luck so far for getting more than 10 images ?